# Get-ADUser info for multiple sub-OUs

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I have what may or may not be a unique issue (but probably not) with what I'm sure is a (relatively) simple solution.  My organization manages several schools across 3 different regions.  I am working on a PS script to go through all of our Users and Computers in AD and find the people machines that are disabled and move them.  The problem lies in the fact that NOT ALL disabled account should be moved as we use Exchange for Rooms & Technology, which are accounts that stay disabled.  What I need to do is to use Get-ADUser and only look at accounts in the "Users" OU at each site.  I know how to do this if I'm just hitting 1 site:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase “OU=Users, OU=SiteName, OU=Region, OU=Company,dc=Company,dc=org” | Select Name,SamAccountName
```

But because we have multiple sites over 3 locations, each with its own "Users" OU, I'm not sure the best way to attack this.  Perhaps I shouldn't use SearchBase?

My hope is that there's a way to do this with a wildcard or something in the Get-ADUser statement, but my instinct is to scrip it with a for loop that somehow pulls the regions, and then the sites, and have that go through, but I'm not really sure if that's right, or how to actually pull that data into an array properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to tackle this at times and found the best way for me was to filter on the DN.

I suspect that your shared mailbox/resource mailboxes and service accounts are located in their own OU's also.

Their maybe other ways but if you try to following and modify to match your requirements.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false' -Searchbase "OU..." | where {$_.distinguishedname -match "Users"}
```

You can also include in the where `-and $_.distinguishedname -notmatch "Shared|mailbox|Resource|SVC` This all depends on what your trying to filter out of the search.

If found that producing a list of users using the above first and then checking this list and then filter them out.

Once that's done you should assign this to a variable and then do a foreach loop on each of the users.